# worksheet change event not triggering?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code in a worksheet object in order to trigger format & formula pasting to the next `lr`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    If Intersect(target, Range("D1:D" & lr)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Rows(lr).Copy
    Rows(lr).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Rows(lr).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Since this is triggered when data for the next new row is appended, shouldn't this trigger on it's own?

Comment: First ensure that events are enabled; `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate Window.

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` turns off the events so it does not fire during the copy paste procedure.  If it errors then sometimes it is left off, one should make sure that there is code to deal with it if it errors so the events are not left off when it should not be.

Comment: And why are you copying the row back on itself.  Don't you want `ROWS(lr+1).PasteSepecial...` so it pastes them in the next row from the one being copied?

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for your help!

Comment: @ScottCraner so I  took out the enable events lines. The only cell changing was in column Z of the last row. it exits the sub on this row: `If Intersect(target, Range("D1:D" & lr)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`

Comment: That line makes it so it only fires if the cell changing is in column D, otherwise it ignores it.

Comment: And you are going to want to leave turning off the events or it will cause an eternal loop.

Comment: so, this is the point where we need more information.  Please tell us exactly what you want to happen and when, be very specific.  Like, "I enter information into cell blah-blah and I want blah-blah to happen to cells in row blah blah."

Comment: In regards to `EnableEvents`, `Rows(lr).EntireRow.PasteSpecial ...` will cause the event to fire again in an infinite loop; it's modifying the sheet.

Comment: @ScottCraner @bigben I have a userform and after the last field is filled out, the user clicks on send data. Already have a sub for this. The last column is `BC`. So once that is triggered, I want this to take the formatting from previous row and apply it to the one that was just created from the userform. also columns "BD:BN" have formulas that I want to bring down to this new row from the previous row

Comment: You are not going to want to use a event for this.  Do this in your code that moves the values.  do the copy/pastespecial BEFORE putting the values in the cells.

Comment: @ScottCraner so I have placed code in before putting values in the cells. the first is pasting formats, which works fine, but the second is pastingformulas and it just pastes the the entire previous row. I only want the formulas from the previous row.

        `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False` this doesn't paste just the formulas, but the entirety of the previous row

Comment: Excel considers static values with formulas when using paste special.  You will want to either then go behind and clear the static values, or you could just copy the cells with the formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change: SpecialCells feat. FillDown

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const Cols As String = "A:BC"
    
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = Columns(Cols).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Columns(Cols).Rows(lCell.Row), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = Rows(lCell.Row - 1)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim frg As Range: Set frg = rrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    Intersect(rrg.Resize(2), frg.EntireColumn).FillDown
    
    rrg.Copy
    rrg.Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    
    rrg.Cells(1).Offset(1).Select

SafeExit:
    If Application.CutCopyMode Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this! this works well for formatting, but the columns that have formulas that I need filled down still aren't there

Comment: Try deleting (clearing) all rows after the last row containing formulas. Then when entering new data in any of the cells in the next available row in columns `A:BC`, it should trigger.

Comment: After thinking it through, the formatting will not work if there are no formulas, which leads me to the conclusion that the formulas had to have been copied down. Any feedback is appreciated.